# Getting redirection loop issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I am using separate theme in our worpdress website. So that the url will be generated like

http://mywebsite.com/myproj/blog/project/post-name

In that above URL, I have hosted the wordpress instance under the blog folder.

I am trying to remove the string "project" from the url. SO I have written the below code. which is redirecting to the corresponding url but the page is working properly. Getting an below error "The page isn't redirecting properly".

What is the issue

Below is the htaccess that I am using

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproj/blog/
RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ $1 [L,R,QSA]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /myproj/blog/index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Why don't you remove `project` form the path on the URL setting on your admin panel then you won't need `RewriteRule ^project/(.*)$ $1 [L,R,QSA]` which is causing an infinite loop.

Comment: I tried, it is not possible. Because by default it is adding since we use Gridnik  wordpress theme.

Comment: is project a custom post type provided by the theme?

Comment: Yes. this is the custom post type.

Comment: so by default wordpress permalink structure the post_type slug will be added to the url before the post_name param. like http://www.example.com/%post_type%/%post_name% There are ways of removing it some plugins are available which you could use.

Comment: have you achieved it?